# reinforcement learning: PPO vs. DDPG vs. TRPO - difference and intuition

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I know there is a lot of blog talk about the PPO, DDPG and TRPO, but I am wondering would it be possible to explain the differences of these methods in layman's term? What's the intuition behind them without using the complex mathematics? Thanks!